# How to manipulate the CURRENT_DATE() in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a scheduled query in BigQuery that appends data to a table based on a large view. The view references other views which, in their turn, reference other views. At the lowest level, the views get data based on the CURRENT_DATE(). It's something like this:

View 1 (view_1):

`` SELECT Date, COUNT(1) as RecordCount FROM `project_name.dataset_name.first_table` WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) GROUP BY Date ``

View 2 (view_2):

`` SELECT Date, COUNT(1) as RecordCount FROM `project_name.dataset_name.second_table` WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) GROUP BY Date ``

View 3 (view_3):
`` SELECT a.Date, a.RecordCount, b.RecordCount FROM `project_name.dataset_name.view_1` a LEFT JOIN `project-name.dataset_name.view_2` b ON a.Date = b.Date ``

What I want is something like a backfill; manipulate the CURRENT_DATE() so that I can build this table for a certain historical period. I have tried testing this using the 'manual runs', but it always outputs the same data. The scheduled query I wrote is something like:

`` SELECT COUNT(1) as RecordCount FROM `project_name.dataset_name.table_name` WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) ``

When I start a manual run starting at 01-01-2020 and ending at 31-01-2020, the output in the destination table is always the number of records for yesterday (which means CURRENT_DATE() is still today).

If I remember correctly, I could do this in the past using the 'backfill', but the output in that seems different than the manual runs which replaced the backfill.

The expected output is something like:

2020-03-02 3294 11201

2020-03-01 2984 10812

2020-02-29 3121 12121

2020-02-28 2912 12239
.....

But the output of the manual runs is:

2020-03-02 3294 11201

2020-03-02 3294 11201

2020-03-02 3294 11201

2020-03-02 3294 11201

.....

Comment: Could you add some examples of the output you are getting and the output desired?

Comment: Please consider that the Biquery Dates are in the UTC zone, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#current_date

Comment: I will add it to the original question.

Comment: How are you doing the manual execution? If this execution is done in the same date looking for the dates between 01-01-2020 and 31-01-2020, the CURRENT_DATE function will always return the same date.

Comment: @ebeltran In the BigQuery UI (old one), there is the option to 'start manual runs' in the scheduled query overview page. I put the start date (i.e. 01-01-2020) and end date (31-01-2020) there. When I run these, I see the run date for the query is correct in the overview (starts at 01-01-2020), but the output of the query is the real date of today (and not 01-01-2020). I used this functionality in the past with success, but something seems off now. New UI same story with backfill; not the correct results.

Comment: @ebeltran In the overview, the 'run date' and 'scheduled time' differ in date (which is good). If I try the backfill now, the run date is '01-01-2020' and scheduled time is now (which is also good). But the output of the CURRENT_DATE() function is still today, which should be 01-01-2020 (since that's the run date).

Comment: In here, the current_date() always returns the date according to the actual date, it will never return the date related to the "run date", for that you have the parameter @run_date

Comment: This issue is confusing, if possible, could you add some screenshots of how you are using the classic Bigquery UI and the new one? also the results you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you're using schedule queries its safer to use `@run_date` (type `date`) or `@run_time` (type `timestamp`) than `current_date()` which can be undefined or of a context relevant to the local runtime. An additional advantage is whilst using backfill @run_time/@run_date is populated with the mocked date as define in the backfill request. See this [Google Doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries)

So in your queries you would change it like so

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(1) as RecordCount FROM `project_name.dataset_name.first_table` WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY) GROUP BY Date
```

`@run_date` is of BigQuery type `date` so it should work okay with `DATE_ADD`

User @ebeltran has also mentioned this in the comments on the op

Comment: Interesting stuff, thank you. The advantages you named are correct. I think the answer you provided is the answer I was looking for.

The disadvantage however is that you can't run a normal query with @run_date, so when you have a view (let's say all yesterday's payments), you can't save it as a normal view and use it ad-hoc (give me yesterday's payments for Europe) and for your SQ (select aggregates from yesterday's payments to be added to an aggregates-table).

Comment: True in console, but you can switch it out for the string date i.e. '2021-11-09' not ideal but maybe solution. Alternatively having a commented out declare statement to define a variable like so
`DECLARE run_date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE();` then just remove the comment and @ from your query, very hacyky but works.
Alternatively you can use a different method to run the query detailed in the Docs https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#bq